# Как подключить ButterKnife?

Tags: android

Есть ли для Android studio что - то типо плагина или кнопки чтобы нажать и автоматически подключить ButterKnife.

А то для каждого приложения прописывать все эти apt defenders и т.д. Надоедает.

Штука очень хорошая, жалко Гугл не внедряет ее по умолчанию. Одной кнопкой можно сразу получить список id всего layout. Чем не мечта программиста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Существуют множество DI Framework, и гугл не раз писали про осторожность их внедрения. Более того, у них есть свои минусы, и ситуации при которых вы будете ловить экзепшны, там где не должны, perfomance, memory и тд, кончено это упрощает жизнь, но не без боли в проектах, поэтому аккуратно. Если вы так часто создаете проекты и пользуйтесь одними и теми же lib, рефакторите один и тот же код каждый раз, для этого существует Custom Projects In Android Studio. Это именно то, что вы выбираете при создании нового проекта, так вот, вы можете настроить свой кастомный. 
Если вам нужен только файл gradle, смотрите в templates :

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\android\lib\templates\gradle-projects\NewAndroidModule\root\build.gradle.ftl
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вы также можете подключить libs, из структуры проекта AS, это очень удобно и зависимости подтягиваются автоматически. Вот пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Насчет templates это очень интерестно. Видимо то что мне нужно)

Answer (score 1):

По поводу плагина не знаю, но
неужели так лень сделать Ctrl+C - Ctrl+V ≈ 10 строк 
или я что то недопонимаю ?

Для подключения BK необходимо и достаточно вставить в *build.gradle* уровня проекта

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
   }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
  }
}
```

И в *build.gradle* модуля

```
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

dependencies {
  compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.1.0'
  apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.1.0'
}
```

Строка *apply plu...*  должна быть в самом верху

Собственно инструкция самого [Джэка Вортона](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife)